# Обстоятельство условия

Tags: синтаксис

**Если б в России убрали коррупцию, я бы жил в России.**

"Если б в России убрали коррупцию" - это обстоятельство условия, как разграничить обстоятельство от сложного предложения?

Comment: Вопрос непонятен ("как разграничить обстоятельство от сложного предложения?"). Что подразумевались под словом "разграничить"? Вы хотели спросить, как отличить простое предложение с обстоятельством от сложного предложения?

Comment: _Антон Логунов:

"Если б в России убрали коррупцию" - это обстоятельство условия_ === Почему Вы так решили?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) **Обстоятельство условия**: При условии отсутствия коррупции я бы жил в России.

2) **СПП с придаточным условия**: Если бы в России не было коррупции, я бы жил в России.

Сходное содержание выражено разными грамматическими формами.

Обстоятельство условия – это член простого предложения. Придаточное условие – это самостоятельное предложение с собственной предикативной основой.  В приведенном примере это односоставное безличное предложение со сказуемым *не было.*